# Default output width for isql

Tags: isql

When I use isql with the same connect string and execute the same query in two different hosts, I get different result formatting -- one wraps each record after X characters, whereas the other host displays one line per record.

So I figured that I could use -w200 as an option when connecting isql in the connect string and the output is the same on both hosts.  However, I would like to make both hosts output the same as there must be a default setting for the display width that takes effect if -w is not specified.

How is this setting specified?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the default is supposed to be 80.  If you are seeing different outputs on different hosts, it could be the way the host terminal is configured.